# Como puedo insertar datos usando Python en un treeview sin usar base de datos?

Tags: python, tkinter

Estoy haciendo una tabla de productos y me interesaria poder insertarle los productos y que se vean en ventana sin la necesidad de usar una base de datos. Estoy aprendiendo Python.

Comment: Serías tan amable de contestar lo siguiente: ¿Dónde estás tratando de crear la tabla? ¿Cuándo mencionas treeview a que te refieres exactamente?

Comment: Estoy tratando de crearla en Python usando la libreria de tkinter y treeview es el elemento grafico que uso para que se vea el listado de productos que quiero mostrar.

Comment: La manera de insertar datos en un treeview es la misma independientemente de donde salga la informacion a insertar. No entiendo tu duda por este motivo.

Comment: Mi problema es que utilizo tree.insert("", 'end',text = "", values=("")) en la función destinada a esto y no se insertan los datos.

Comment: Si haces eso, en realidad el item **si** se inserta, pero con todos los valores en blanco. Tienes que pasarle a values una tupla en la cual cada item corresponde a un numero de columna. Por ejemplo si pasas la tupla (1, 2, 3) se agrega un item así: `|1|2|3|` donde `|` es la separación entre columnas. (nota: esto se salta la columna "#0")

Comment: Claro, entiendo. Mi idea que el usuario escriba mediante un Entry los productos a listar en el treeview. Entonces mediante un botón tenia que hacer una función que se encarge de agregar los productos al treeview, no se si me explico.